# GAE/Go hang up on local development server

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I am developing GAE/Go + gin application.

We have now about 25 handlers like this.

```
func init() {
    r := gin.New()
    r.POST("/path/to/some1", func1)   //  ^
    r.POST("/path/to/some2", func2)   //  |
            :                         //  | about 25 handlers
    r.POST("/path/to/someX", funcX)   //  v
}
```

I added another handler `funcY` to above code. and I invoked local development server, but it hangs up during start up.

```
func init() {                         // Hang up during start up.
    r := gin.New()
    r.POST("/path/to/some1", func1)   
    r.POST("/path/to/some2", func2)   
            :                         
    r.POST("/path/to/someX", funcX)   
    r.POST("/path/to/someY", funcY)   
}
```

The console log is as below. No message after this.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\Gogland 171.3780.106\bin\runnerw.exe" C:/go_appengine\goapp.bat serve C:/path/to/app.yaml
INFO     2017-05-26 15:03:02,552 devappserver2.py:764] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2017-05-26 15:03:02,996 api_server.py:268] Starting API server at: http://localhost:56094
INFO     2017-05-26 15:03:03,000 dispatcher.py:199] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2017-05-26 15:03:03,000 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
```

`funcY` has no problem because when I remove `func1`, it starts up normally.

```
func init() {                         // This works without problem.
    r := gin.New()
    r.POST("/path/to/some2", func2)   
            :                         
    r.POST("/path/to/someX", funcX)   
    r.POST("/path/to/someY", funcY)   
}
```

Does gin have maximum number of handler? If so, how can I raise it? Or do I have another way to solve this?

**[UPDATE]**
This looks to be the local development server problem. When I deployed to the actual GAE, my app works without problem. How can I solve this problem in the local development server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self resolved.

I set `gin` to `release mode` and my app works fine.

```
gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)
```